# Login com Facebook - Iserir imagem de perfil em um <input type="file">

Tags: api, facebook

boa tarde.

Têm alguma forma de fazer com que o login com facebook, pegue a imagem de perfil do usuário e "armazene" em um input type="file" de um formulário? Para funcionar como se o usuário tivesse feito o upload dessa imagem.

Exemplo:
Eu sei que tem como fazer o login pegar o Nome do usuário e armazenar no value="" de um input, mas não sei como fazer isso para arquivos.

Obrigado.

Comment: Olá.. A princípio, se você consegue pegar o public_profile de um usuário, nele tem a "picture", que é a foto de perfil da pessoa... Aparentemente retorna um link para a foto da pessoa. Isso é suficiente?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tem diversas formas de conseguir a imagem de perfil do usuário, através do ID na web, podemos conseguir da seguinte maneira:

http://graph.facebook.com/" + facebookId + "/picture?type=square
http://graph.facebook.com/1222810918/picture?type=square

Tanto o ID quanto o link p/ imagem podem ser retornados no login com a API do facebook. Existem outros tipos(tamanhos), para mais informações da uma olhada [aqui](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user/picture).

Agora, armazenar via código um arquivo em um `<input type="file" />` acredito não ser possível por questões de segurança. Vale dar uma repensada em como fazer essa parte de simular o usuário fazendo upload de uma imagem do facebook.